# Change variable value in Script shell with sed command ; error syntax

Tags: sed, blockchain

```
sed -i 's|from_infura_hex=?|from_infura_hex=$(curl -s -X POST --connect-timeout 5 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data \'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}\' https://ropsten.infura.io/X/X | jq .result | xargs)|' /home/ec2-user/LastBlockNode.sh
```

I tried to execute this command but I always get this error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

The purpose of this command is to modify the value `from_infura_hex=?` in the script LastBlockNode.sh by the curl command.

Can anyone help with this sed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you choose a pipe character `|` as a delimiter for `s` command,
  the character should not appear in pattern or replacement without escaping. As you are using `|` as a pipeline in your command, it is better to pick other character such as `#`.
- You cannot nest single quotes even if you escape it with a backslash.
- In order to use a command substitution within the replacement,
  you need to say `sed -i '/pattern/'"$(command)"'/'`, not
  `sed -i '/pattern/$(command)/'`.

Then would you please try something like:

```
sed -i 's#from_infura_hex=?#from_infura_hex='"$(curl -s -X POST --connect-timeout 5 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":
\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[],\"id\":1}" https://ropsten.infura.io/X/X | jq .result | xargs)"'#' /home/ec2-user/LastBlockNode.sh
```

But it will be safer and more readable to split the command into
multiple lines:

```
replacement="$(curl -s -X POST --connect-timeout 5 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' https://ropsten.infura.io/X/X | jq .result | xargs)"
sed -i 's#from_infura_hex=?#from_infura_hex='"$replacement"'#' /home/ec2-user/LastBlockNode.sh
```

Please note I have not tested the commands above with the actual data.
If either of them still do not work, please let me know with the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried the two solution that you give me but in the both of them the replacement of the variable will be will null as shown below.

The value will be displayed in the file like this i tried even to modify some quote but i didn't succeded.
from_infura_hex=null

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It will be easier to debug with the 2nd approach. First please execute `echo "$replacement"` to see what is assigned to the variable. If it is empty or `null` then execute the command between `"$(` and `)"` meaning from `curl` to `xargs`. Please carefully copy & paste the command line without modifying the quotes. If the output still has a problem, remove the pipeline `| jq .result | xargs` and examine the output. Good luck.